# C: Float value to method but value becomes 0

Tags: c, methods

I am trying to call a method with a float value. But the values turns 0 when I put it in the method.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char *from, *to;
from = NULL;
to = NULL;
float value = FLT_MAX;

// Kommandozeilenparameter einlesen
int ret;
while ((ret=getopt(argc, argv, "f:t:v:")) != -1) {
    switch (ret) {
    case 'f':
        from = optarg;
        break;
    case 't':
        to = optarg;
        break;
    case 'v':
        value = atof(optarg);
        break;
    default:
        printf("hallo");
        //printHilfe();
        break;
    }
}
printf ("%c %c %.2f \n", *from, *to, value);
konvert (*from, *to, value);

return 0;
}

float konvert(char from, char to, float value) {
     printf ("%c %c %.2f \n", from, to, value);
     method...
}
```

When I print the values in main before I call the konvert method all values are correct. But once the value is passed to the method it turns 0.

Comment: Why not start by calling `konvert` with a hard coded float value, then you can rest assured that you can pass a `float` to a function and figure out why your argument parsing isn't working

Comment: also, you should include the execution of your program and the full results

Comment: Your code does not even compile for me.  GCC complains that the implicit declaration of `konvert()` guessed at the point of the call to that function in `main()` is not compatible with the actual definition that appears (only) later.  If your compiler is not at least warning about that issue then you need a better compiler.  If it *is* warning you, then why do you not pay attention to it?  One way to solve that particular issue would be to move function `konvert()` ahead of `main()` in your source.  With that change, your program seems to work for me.

Comment: The comment of @john Bollinger is likely the answer. Compiler does not see a declaration of `konvert()` in the point where it is called and applies the 'default prototype' where all parameters are int. So it converts `value` to int. Maybe you confuse this situation with C++  where references to members of a class can occur before definition. Not the case here. `kconvert` is not a class  method. Just a free-standing function.

Comment: @ddbug Almost — with the default argument promotions in effect, `float` is promoted to `double`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Hmm yes i stand corrected